# Adding a method to an object in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got an AngularJS webapplication where I use ng-repeat on an array of persons. The json array defines a firstname, lastname and age of the persons.

In my table I'm trying to apply a CSS class to all the young persons using the ng-class directive.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Age</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search" ng-class="{success: person.isYoung()}">
        <td>{{person.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{person.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice I'm trying to call person.isYoung(), which is the method I'm having trouble with. Things work if I use

```
ng-class="{success: person.age < 30}"
```

but, I want to move that logic into the Controller instead.

Inside my Controller I've added this;

```
$scope.isYoung = function (person) {
    return person.age < 30;    
}
```

but it seems like that isn't called.

What should my method definition in app.js look like for me to get this working?

```
ng-class="{success: person.isYoung()}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the function is

```
isYoung(person)
```

So that's what you need to use in your template:

```
ng-class="{success: isYoung(person)}"
```

If you want to be able to use `person.isYoung()`, then you need to add this function to all the persons in the array :

```
angular.forEach(persons, function(person) {
    person.isYoung = function() {
        return person.age < 30;
    }
});
```